# Glide doesn't load images

Tags: android, image-loading, android-glide

I have an issue when loading images from web. There are some URLs when I hit them with Glide then it didn't show the image. For example:

http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_wOtGwObrPyI/SgbEunh78vI/AAAAAAAAAx4/UAk7SuQkUu8/s320/s%C3%BCt%C3%A9s+1146.jpg

The URL is UTF-8 encoded.

Usage of Glide:

```
Glide.with(this.context).load(currentRecipe.getRecipeThumbnailUrl()).into(categoryIcon);
```

A part of the layout of the ImageView:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/categoryPic" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

In the console I got the following:
SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

I've searched around but hadn't found any useful solution.

Device: Xiaomi Redmi 1S
Android version: 4.4.4
Glide version: 3.7.0

Comment: I don't think you can use wrap_content for the width and the height, Glide needs to know the size to load. Try setting a fixed size to see if that loads your images, if it does, then you know what you need to do.

Answer (score -1):

Robert Papp said [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/glidelibrary/ivUf8pYm5TM):

> SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null usually means that
>   BitmapFactory.decode couldn't figure out how to handle the input.

So I think at this point that your image name: `sütés+1146.jpg` cant be handled by 
`BitmapFactory.decode.`

Hope this helps!!